# Iterate through 2 lists at once Neo4j

Tags: list, foreach, neo4j, list-comprehension

I have two lists of numbers of the same length.
I want to go through both lists at once, multiply that pair of numbers and add them to an accumulator. In python I'd do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
acc = 0

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    acc = acc + x*y
```

I've looked at `foreach`and `list comprehension` constructs in Neo4j but couldn't make it work... what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using reduce and a range iterator based on the list size :

```
WITH [1,2,3] AS list1, [4,5,6] AS list2
RETURN reduce(
   acc=0, 
   x IN range(0, size(list1)-1) | 
   acc + (list1[x] + list2[x])
) AS total
```